# Is there a way to show the default date icon for input with type text?

Tags: html, input

I have a form with input `type="text"`, but it is actually a date field in a specific format. I need to show the calendar icon in the right corner of this form.

```html
<input class="form-control" value="01-12-2020" placeholder="Start date" type="text" name="started_at" id="started_at">
```

If I change input to `type="date"`, icon is showed but also it change behavior of the input, it show in placeholder 'mm/dd/yyyy' and breaks js functionality for this input.

Is there a way to show icon for calendar bun for `input=text` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a `<span>` or `<i>` tag for example:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i> 
<input class="input-field" type="text">
```

Here you would see an envelope icon in the `<input>` field.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to add an icon next to the input is adding an image. Add an image tag just before the input tag.

```
<img src="data.png"><input class="form-control" value="01-12-2020" placeholder="Start date" type="text" name="started_at" id="started_at">
```